# Como fazer uma atualização tipo DLC, com unity

Tags: unity3d, atualização, sql-update

Olá!

Gostaria de saber se é possível, criar uma atualização para um jogo (IOS/Android) tipo DLC, ou seja o usuário terá a opção de incluir essa extensão ao seu jogo atual. Já testei com AssetsBundle, mais pelo que li na documentação, ele não carrega os scripts, somente texturas, objetos e etc, para o cache do game. Enquanto o que eu precisava era adicionar novas coisas dentro da pasta Assets, sem ter que baixar o jogo todo novamente.

Comment: Cara, dá uma olhada melhor no AssetsBundle, se não me engano ele carrega objetos novos e estes objetos poderão estar associados a scripts. Olha neste link aqui [Asstes Bundles Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/assetbundles-and-assetbundle-manager)